# laravel 5.2 store image inside database

Tags: image, laravel, upload

my controller is:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request, ['title' => 'required',
                             'date' => 'required',
                             'image_1' => 'mimes:png,jpeg',
                            ]);

  $user = Auth::user()->id;
  $report = new Report($request->all());
  $report->author_id = $user;

  $image = $request->file('image_1');
  $ext = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $path = public_path('uploads/reports/' . $image . $ext);

  $report->image_1 = $path;
  $report->save();

  Session::flash('flash_message', 'Report added!');

  return redirect('dash/reports');
}
```

all ok without name of my image, my app store data like

```
/var/www/localhost/htdocs/gemini/public/uploads/reports//tmp/phpul0PNipng
```

why use /tmp/randomstring name?

Comment: You may also try using the intervention API for image management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$request->file('image_1')
```

This returns an object, not a filename. You get extension correctly, so you can get the filename the same way:

```
$path = public_path('uploads/reports/' . $image->getClientOriginalName() . $ext);
```